# Observable.Create: CancellationToken doesn't transition to IsCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

Take this little script (designed in LINQPad but should run everywhere):

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(() => Worker()).Wait();
}

async Task Worker()
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't want any synchronization!");

    BaseClass provider = new Implementation();
    Func<IObserver<TimeSpan>, CancellationToken, Task> subscribeAsync =
        provider.CreateValues;
    var observable = Observable.Create(subscribeAsync);

    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(5500).Token; // gets cancelled after 5.5s
    cancellation.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("token is cancelled now"));
    await observable
        .Do(ts =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}; cancelled: {1}",
                ts,
                cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
            cancellation.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        })
        .ToTask(cancellation)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
    // allow implementers to use async-await
    public abstract Task CreateValues(IObserver<TimeSpan> observer, CancellationToken cancellation);
}

class Implementation : BaseClass
{
    // creates Values for 10s; entirely CPU-bound: no way for async-await hence return Task.CompletedTask
    public override Task CreateValues(IObserver<TimeSpan> observer, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        try
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1} cancelled:{2}", i, j, cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
                    Thread.Sleep(333);
                }

                if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested) // !! never gets true !!
                    throw new ApplicationException("token is cancelled");

                observer.OnNext(sw.Elapsed);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `Implementation.CreateValues` justs keeps running for the entire 10 seconds instead of stopping after 5.5s. The `CancellationToken` passed in by `Observable.Create` doesn't even transition to a cancelled state (the original token of course does)!

**Is it a bug? Is it my fault by doing something wrong?**

Output is:

```
0/0 cancelled:False
0/1 cancelled:False
0/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:01.0205951; cancelled: False
1/0 cancelled:False
1/1 cancelled:False
1/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:02.0253279; cancelled: False
2/0 cancelled:False
2/1 cancelled:False
2/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:03.0274035; cancelled: False
3/0 cancelled:False
3/1 cancelled:False
3/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:04.0294796; cancelled: False
4/0 cancelled:False
4/1 cancelled:False
4/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:05.0315332; cancelled: False
5/0 cancelled:False
5/1 cancelled:False
token is cancelled now
5/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:06.0335601; cancelled: True
6/0 cancelled:False
6/1 cancelled:False
6/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:07.0436211; cancelled: True
7/0 cancelled:False
7/1 cancelled:False
7/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:08.0457921; cancelled: True
8/0 cancelled:False
8/1 cancelled:False
8/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:09.0477509; cancelled: True
9/0 cancelled:False
9/1 cancelled:False
9/2 cancelled:False
Elapsed: 00:00:10.0498751; cancelled: True
[AggregateException] at Main/Task.Wait()
```

Comment: This seems to be a forced usage of Rx. Indicators of this IMO are 1) mixing of Task and Rx, 2) Passing in `IObserver<T>` as a parameter (not returning an `IObservable<T>`3) Using `ToTask` on an `IObservable` and ignoring the result `TimeSpan`. I suggest you do this with either TPL/Task or Rx, but pick one (or something else entirely).

Comment: @LeeCampbell I already switched to TPL-Dataflow since everything else is Task based already. But: 1) Rx contains many XxxAsync methods and claims to be an ideal companion to Tasks 2) that is the method signature which `Observable.Create()` (Rx!) expects 3) why should I have interrest in the last value the observable has been signaled?

Comment: I dont think "Rx claims to be an ideal companion to Tasks". It can work with Task to avoid a burdensome integration, but predominantly I see the recommendation of use one or the other. The `Observable.Create` signature in my experience is almost exclusively used with a closure/lambda so the passing of `IObserver<T>` is internalized to just the scope of the method. My 3rd point was that if you dont care about any of the values of an observable sequence it can be worth question the usage of one. Good to hear to you came to a result with TPL-Dataflow :-)

Comment: @LeeCampbell I do care of any single value of the observable. That's what the `Do()` method is for. In the original (non-sample) code the abstract method really did return `IObserverable` and most implementations wrapped it with `Observable.Create`. When anoymous methods only rely on `this` I prefer to implement them non-anonymous so the callstack contains useful names.

Comment: Eeewww. So it was a pretty nasty use of Rx. Glad you moved to a more appropriate tool

Answer (score 6):

The cancellation token getting passed to the `subscribeAsync` function is instantiated by the `Observable.Create` call and is not the cancellation token you're instantiating.

As per the `Observable.Create` overload summary:

> Creates an observable sequence from a specified cancellable
>   asynchronous Subscribe method. The CancellationToken passed to the
>   asynchronous Subscribe method is tied to the returned disposable
>   subscription, allowing best-effort cancellation.

In short, the cancellation token will get cancelled when you dispose of the subscription, not after the specified delay.

You should be able to refactor your code as follows to make it work:

```
Observable.Create(observer => subscribeAsync(observer, cancellation));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm aware that it is a different CancellationToken and I really do want to abort as soon as the Observer stops observing. The entire thing even starts to work when I replace `Thread.Sleep(333);` with `await Task.Delay(333);` (which induces removing `return Task.CompletedTask;` and adding `async` to method declaration).

Comment: Ah, I see now you're using the ```.ToTask(cancellation)``` to dispose of the observable. Apologies.
It is worth noting that the ToTask [overloads introduce concurrency](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/21) which may be causing your issue. I wrote [a blog post](http://ian.bebbs.co.uk/posts/RxVsTpl) about this a while back.

Comment: Hmm. Even a single `await Task.Yield();` at the beginning of the method is enough to make it work as intended. Should I go with this for overrides which don't call any async methods?

Comment: I'd suggest you endeavour to stay entirely in Rx or entirely in Tpl and not mix. Terminating/Completing an observable after a specific amount of time is very easy. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Maybe I should consider using TPL-Dataflow, I'm not sure.

The "specific amount of time" is purely for testing purposes. Normally the cancellation will be triggered by user or by app shutdown.

The existing flow is all async-await, but one of the methods has to process an unknown number of elements which come in with delay, and I don't want the worker thread being reserved by just blocking on a foreach loop, which itself has to use tricks (BlockingCollection<>) to provide an IEnumerable -- using IObservable looked just more natural for this.

Comment: Migrated to TPL-Dataflow (see my own pseudo answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the question but a rewrite of the sample code using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow inplace of System.Reactive (far too much code for being posted as a comment):

This has several advantages:

1. since the `observer` parameter is now a `Task` every implementation has something to `await` for.
2. the processing code previously in `Do()` (now in `ActionBlock`) can itself be implemented async if desired.
3. integrated buffering if desired.
4. it's decoupled = technology agnostic: My interface is `Func<TimeSpan, Task<bool>>` and so there is no dependency on Rx or TPL-Dataflow or what else.

New code:

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(() => Worker()).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("DONE");
}

async Task Worker()
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't want any synchronization!");

    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(55000).Token; // gets cancelled after 5.5s
    cancellation.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("token is cancelled now"));

    var flow = new ActionBlock<TimeSpan>(
        async ts =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[START] Elapsed: {0}; cancelled: {1}", ts, cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
            await Task.Delay(2500).ConfigureAwait(false); // processing takes more time than items need to produce
            Console.WriteLine("[STOP] Elapsed: {0}; cancelled: {1}", ts, cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            BoundedCapacity = 2, // Buffer 1 item ahead
            EnsureOrdered = true,
            CancellationToken = cancellation,
        });

    Func<TimeSpan, Task<bool>> observer = ts => flow.SendAsync(ts, cancellation);

    BaseClass provider = new Implementation();
    await provider.CreateValues(observer, cancellation).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("provider.CreateValues done");

    flow.Complete();
    await flow.Completion.ConfigureAwait(false);
    Console.WriteLine("flow completed");
}

abstract class BaseClass
{
    // allow implementers to use async-await
    public abstract Task CreateValues(Func<TimeSpan, Task<bool>> observer, CancellationToken cancellation);
}

class Implementation : BaseClass
{
    public override async Task CreateValues(Func<TimeSpan, Task<bool>> observer, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        try
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1} cancelled:{2}", i, j, cancellation.IsCancellationRequested);
                    Thread.Sleep(333);
                }

                if (cancellation.IsCancellationRequested)
                    throw new ApplicationException("token is cancelled");

                var value = sw.Elapsed;
                var queued = await observer(value); // use of "observer" encorces async-await even if there is nothing else async
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] '{1}' @ {2}", queued ? "enqueued" : "skipped", value, sw.Elapsed);

                if (!queued)
                    ; // Dispose item
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of way I would do this:

```
void Main()
{
    Task.Run(() => Worker()).Wait();
}

async Task Worker()
{
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Don't want any synchronization!");

    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource(5500).Token; // gets cancelled after 5.5s

    cancellation.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("token is cancelled now"));

    var until = Observable.Create<Unit>(o => cancellation.Register(() =>
    {
        o.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        o.OnCompleted();
    }));

    var observable =
    (
        Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(333.0))
            .Zip(
                from i in Observable.Range(0, 10)
                from j in Observable.Range(0, 3)
                select $"{i}/{j} cancelled:{cancellation.IsCancellationRequested}",
                (_, x) => x)
    ).TakeUntil(until);
        
    await observable.Do(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
}
```

The key is the `until` observable that basically watches for the cancellation and produces a `Unit` and then completes. It allows the use of the normal reactive operators.